# Disable orange outline highlight on focus

Tags: android, focus, highlight, outline

I am coding an app using jQuery, jqTouch and phonegap and have run across a persistent problem which arises when a user submits a form using the Go button on the soft keyboard.

Although it is easy to get the cursor to move to the appropriate form input element by using `$('#input_element_id').focus()`, the orange outline highlight always returns to the last input element on the form. (The highlight does not show up when the form is submitted using the form submit button.)

What I need is to find a way either to disable the orange highlight completely or else make it move to the same input element as the cursor.

So far, I have tried adding the following to my CSS:

```
.class_id:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This works in Chrome but not on the emulator or on my phone. I have also tried editing the jqTouch `theme.css` to read:

```
ul li input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); and
    -webkit-focus-ring-color:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

With no effect.
I have also tried each of the following additions to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNone"
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoEnterAction"
```

None of which have any effect.

Update: I have done some more troubleshooting with this and to date have found:

1. The outline property works only on Chrome, not on the Android browser.
2. The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` property does in fact work on the Android browser, though not on Chrome. It disables the highlight on focus as well as on tapping.
3. The `-webkit-focus-ring-color` property does not seem to work on either browser.

Answer (score 212):

Try:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;  // i.e. Nexus5/Chrome and Kindle Fire HD 7''
```

Comment: it doesnt work with android 4.0.4 - anybody has experienced the same? (it works on previous versions and 4.1)

Comment: android 4.0.4 works with:    
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;

Comment: @oori it does, however that "breaks" iOS by causing the keyboard to pop up.

Comment: @Max, you comment isn't clear.  on iOS - ofcourse the keyboard pops-up once you focus into an input/textarea..  please explain

Comment: @oori Ah, I suppose that's not completely clear.  For inputs, it makes sense, but this css style is also used for non-input elements.  I'm trying to use the user-modify flag to disable the orange flash when you click a link on the Galaxy S III (Android 4.0.4) for example, and while it works, it causes the keyboard to pop up for iPhone when it doesn't for Android -- even for an anchor tag!  Hence "breaking" (even if iPhone's behavior *might* be more correct).

Comment: @oori Okay?  That doesn't help with non-input non-textarea elements, which was the subject of my comment.

Comment: * { -webkit-user-modify: read-only; } Worked for my non-textarea elements on Android.

Comment: also add -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; , solved it for i.e. Nexus5(Chrome) and Kindle Fire HD 7''. All other options did not help for these devices/browser. Take care, Firefox and Opera did not need the line on Nexus5. I have taken over the line from one of the other answers below. It was the only way for me to remove tab highlighting on Nexus5 (Chrome) and Kindle Fire HD 7''.

Comment: @Max I am facing the same issue, have you any workaround ? If yes please share.

Comment: after adding this also orange border is not hiding in lollipop

Answer (score 46):

Work on Android Default, Android Chrome and iOS Safari 100%

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Comment: Instead of using `*` you can just use `button`, if your issue is with buttons for instance.

Answer (score 36):

```
* {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
}
```

in your css file.
It worked for me !

Answer (score 18):

Remove the orange box on input focus for Androids

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);    
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

**tap-highlight-color** for most versions

**user-modify** for 4.0.4

Comment: Been searching for a fix [Android 4.1.2] for a few days now. This is the only one that worked. A big thank you!

Comment: @Ben the above answer works for sure...    make a plunkr/jsfiddle with your code, so we can see and assist you.

Comment: @Ben user-modify for 4.0.4 is not good solution any other solution if you have then please share it.

Answer (score 12):

Try for Focus Line

```
body, textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

Comment: Only working solution for Android 4.2 devices and similar.

Answer (score 10):

Be aware that using this CSS `-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;` WILL remove that horrible highlight 'bug' - BUT it may kill your devices ability to provide a specific keyboard. For us running Android 4.0.3 on a Samsung Tab 2, we could no longer get the numeric keyboard. Even using type='number' &/or type='tel' . Very frustrating! 
BTW, setting tap highlight colour did nothing to resolve this issue for this device and OS config. We are running Safari for android.

Comment: how you are running Safari for android.

Comment: Hey @Amit, its been a long time since i answered this! it was just running straight out of the device as factory standard i would say... Tab2 was pretty new on the market at the time.

Answer (score 7):

To make sure the `tap-highlight-color` property overriding works for you, consider these things first:

> **Not working:** 
>   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; 
>   // It sometimes triggers the native keyboard to popup when clicking the element
>
> .class:active, .class:focus { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }
>   // It's not working if defined for states
>
> **Working:** 
>   `.class { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`

This case works for **Android from v2.3 to v4.x** even in a PhongeGap application. I tested it on Galaxy Y with Android 2.3.3, on Nexus 4 with Android 4.2.2 and on Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.1.2. So **don't define it for states only for the element** itself.

Comment: This tip is what made it work for me with a WebView on Android 2.3.

Comment: WOOOOW This one worked!! (Android 4.1.2) Goddam! I hate webview fragmentation !!

Answer (score 7):

Use the below code in CSS file

```
  * {
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    :focus {
        outline: 0;
        border:none;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

It's work for me. I hope it work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to share my experience. I didn't really get this to work, and I wanted to avoid the slow css-*. My solution was to download good old Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and add this one to my phonegap project. I then added:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);   /** Disable orange highlight */
```

In my experience this is a faster approach to the *, but it is also an approach to less weird bugs. Combination of tap-highlight, -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only and disabling of for example text highlighting have provided us with a lot of headaces. One of the worst being that suddenly keyboard input stops working and slow keyboard visualization.

Complete CSS-reset with the orange highlight disabled:

```
/**
 * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);   /** Disable orange highlight */
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for me in Ionic, just put in CSS file to overwrite

```
:focus {
    outline-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me on Image Map Area links, the only working solution was to use javascript by capturing the ontouchend event and preventing default browser behavior by returning false on the handler.

with jQuery:

```
$("map area").on("touchend", function() {
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work not only for taps, but hover as well:

```
button, button:hover, li:hover, a:hover , li , a , *:hover, * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this one and worked fine :-

HTML:-

```
<a class="html5logo"  href="javascript:void(0);"  ontouchstart="return true;"></a>
```

css

```
.html5logo {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: url(/img/html5-badge-128.png) no-repeat;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some Androids */
}
.html5logo:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 1);
}
```

Comment: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; -> great, solved it for i.e. Nexus5(Chrome) and Kindle Fire HD 7''. All other options did not help for these devices/browser. Take care, Firefox and Opera did not need the line on Nexus5.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"                 

 />
```

Answer (score -1):

If the design doesn't use outlines, this should do the job:

```
*, *::active, *::focus {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
    outline: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code that disable border outline

> outline: none !important;