# Android done/go/enter does not fire any DOM event in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-softkeyboard

**The Issue:**

Using

```
<input id="my_tel" type="tel" onkeypress="alert(event);"/>

<input id="my_num" type="number" onkeypress="alert(event);" />
```

The issue is that pressing done or enter or go key in android, nothing happens.For all other keys it works fine. When i tried to alert what event is being fired **i found none**.
The keypad does not hide (which is very sad) on pressing go/enter/done button.

However using

> input type="text"

the issue does not exist.

Here is what i tried :

> A. Used input type="text" and do not allow user to enter anything except
>   numbers.
>
> **Problem with this approach** : The user is always presented with the default textual keyboard, and she/he has to switch, from default text to number pad,
>   which is not elegant and a turn off as i have many such pages in my project.
>
> B. Used events like '*touchstart*'and '*touchend*' but no luck.
>
> C. The input box is not even losing focus on key press so the solution
>   [html phonegap android : numeric soft keyboard has next instead of go button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233434/html-phonegap-android-numeric-soft-keyboard-has-next-instead-of-go-button/10017095) is not useful.

**Possible solution :**

We can use the SoftKeyBoard plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SoftKeyboard). And hope that this problem is solved by this. But seriously can't there be a better solution??

**Note** : The problem is **not observed in the iOS app**,just android.

**Another Note** : No DOM event is fired even on pressing  backspace key, but atleast the the backspace key is doing its job. In my case the done/go/enter key does not seem to execute its default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

are you using iScroll?, if you are try removing it for a quick test and see what happens. I use it on a phonegap app and it's doing strange things with the inputs.

Comment: Sorry buddy, but i am not using iscroll.