# Disable orange highlight on a div in WebView

Tags: android, css, webview, cordova

I am making an PhoneGap Android app, and can't turn off the orange highlighting clickable elements.

I have tried all combinations of CSS: -webkit-tap-highlight-color, -webkit-focus-ring-color and -webkit-user-modify, as suggested in

[Disable orange outline highlight on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus)
[Disable orange highlight around links in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669416/disable-orange-highlight-around-links-in-android)

Here is what I have, and it's not doing anything:

```
`* {  
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;   
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;  
    outline: none !important;  
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only !important;  
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}`
```

I'm using Phonegap 2.9.0 and Android 4.1.2, and Calendario plugin from here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/

Is there any hope for disabling this unsightly organe thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div{
-webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, orange thing is still there. I'm trying this out on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, but I'll try it on some other devices soon and report.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you are talking about the outline set by `focus`, so this should help (not tested):

```
div:focus, div:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer isn't getting more love. This the only thing that worked for me in Android 4.0. Note that there is a typo above -- it should be `div:focus, div:active { outline: none; }`

It may be useful to verify that this property has an effect. I used the following to do so: `div:focus { outline:1px solid green; } div:focus { outline:1px solid red; }`

Comment: This is also the only thing that worked for me with Android 4.x (using Brian Rak's version with the typos corrected)

Comment: Worked for me also, Android 4.x including Samsungs. I was looking for removing the outline on buttons with font icons, so I just added "button:focus, button:active" to the selector. Worked flawlessly ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can try by using

```
* {-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;}
```