# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Disable orange outline highlight on focus is not working

Tags: android, css, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a mobile app in worklight 6.1 with one textbox and a textarea. I need to remove the orange outline hightlight on focus in android devices so I have tried all the codes which is written in: [Disable orange outline highlight on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus)".

In IBM Worklight 6.0 this works:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);    
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```

I have tried the same code with IBM Worklight 6.1, but it doesn't work.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div>
    <input type="text"/>
    <textarea>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

The hightlight appears for a fraction of seconds in 6.1.

---

After adding the below code which is the answer given by @Ilya am getting the same output:

[image]

Comment: What is the Android OS version used?

Comment: @Idan Adar Android 4.4.2

Comment: Which HTML widget are we talking about? Only text fields?

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes only textbox and texarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the working code. Tested in devices[Samsung S Duos, Sony Xperia M & Samsung Tab II] with IBM worklight 6.0 & IBM Worklight 6.1.

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, input,textarea{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; 
    border: none !important;
    margin: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need turn off outline before focusing on the Input

```
textarea, input{
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @IdanAdar, I have tried this as well but the result is same.

Comment: I disagree, I have created a new application in Worklight 6.1 with a textarea and text field, applying the above CSS rule made the orange highlight disappear on focus. Tested on a Nexus 5 device running Android OS 4.4.x. In any case, this is not related to Worklight, but to Android and CSS.

Comment: Working here guys... Provide a test case project.

Comment: @IdanAdar 
Maybe problem in border?
Add in this code

 border: none !important;

Comment: @Ilya I have tried the border also  same output as shown above

Answer (score 0):

See this Worklight 6.1.0-based project: [Disable Focus Rings in Android](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8b9mffreb0nrdt/disableFocusRingsInAndroid.zip)

In it I have used the following CSS rules:

```
textarea, input {
    /* Deals with Android 4.x */
    outline: none;

    /* Deals with Android 2.x */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* For some other Androids */
}
```

When focusing on either a `textarea` or an `input` field of type "text" in a Nexus 5 device running Android OS v4.4, the focus ring is not displayed, not even for a fraction of a second:

[image]

If this is not working for you, then you have some other CSS preventing from the CSS rules to be applied...

Comment: I have downloaded the project which you shared[Disable Focus Rings in Android]. I imported into workspace and tested with Samsung S Duos, Sony Xperia M and Samsung Tab II but the result is same. Can this be an issue with Worklight studio Developer edition 6.1?

Comment: No it cannot because this is CSS, Worklight is not the implementor of CSS. This is related to specific devices. As you can see it is working OK with Nexus 5. I do not have the devices you have listed, so I cannot test on them. Are you sure you are not referring to PASSWORD input field?

Comment: @IdanAdar the problem was specifically said that the outline comes during focus of the input field.How can you expect a css code without `:focus` to work. I have downloaded yours and tested since i am amazed to see your code. But unfortunately it didnt work for me. Do you have highlight during normal times.