# How to remove active state from mobile webview elements

Tags: android, css, cordova, android-webview

I'm pulling my hair out here. I believe it must have something to do with the stock browser that is rending the phonegap apps. However I just can't get rid of what I believe is the active state. This does not occur if I browse to the app online.

I have the following in my css:

```
 *::selection {background: transparent;} *:focus {outline: none;}
```

This does happen with all devices I have tested, all be it slightly different outcomes. My **S3** seen below is yellow.

However my Nexus 5 is blue.... In my iPhone 3gs it is dark blue/black in my iPhone 4/5 it is also the same colour.

So I would like to remove this state completely or pick my own colours.

**Samsung S3**
[image: Samsung S3]
**Nexus 5**
[image: Nexus 5]

Comment: you'll find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus (I use this in my apps)

Comment: Awesome dude, add it as the correct answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you'll find the answer here:

[Disable orange outline highlight on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus)

(I use this in my apps)

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;  // i.e. Nexus5/Chrome and Kindle Fire HD 7''
```