# Disable orange highlight mapped area phonegap android? without using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

is there any idea through which orange highlights Disable in android all phone without using CSS

actually all CSS code are not working plzz help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but try this CSS code:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);    
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

This will disable the orange color.
Without CSS it won't work.

Source:
[Disable orange outline highlight on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210481/disable-orange-outline-highlight-on-focus)

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather save him a broken phone.

Comment: is any code which disable it from script cuz CSS code as you mention is not working